# The background distortion when the screen turn from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: android, background, background-image, android-relativelayout

In my fragment , I set the background to a `Relativelayout`.

But when the screen turn from vertical (Portrait) to horizontal (Landscape) , the background image seems like distorted.

It can not set `scaleType` to `Relativelayout`.

Does there has any method can make the background auto scaling when the screen turn from vertical to horizontal?

(Does not need to detect the screen size , just let the background image auto scaling and no distortion)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Relative layout is not a scale type.  RelativeLayout is a class that holds views and allows you to define where they are relative to one another.  Scale types are found here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: So...if I don't use Scale types , does there any idea can make the background auto scaling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `Image-view` inside your `Relative Layout` and use it as a background, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myBg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/my_bg_image" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way you can put other views on top of your bg and it will scale properly.

Comment: This is not correct way to provide background for RelativeLayout as we are adding one more layer to just adding background to Layout where android has provision to use this more efficiently

Comment: I prefer adding a layer insead of another image and another layout.

Comment: That's fine Ayoub, but this is not best practice for it. Please check [This Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If your background image is created for  **Portrait** mode and if it has graphics or texture involved then it is obvious that it will be distorted when seen in **Landscape** mode.

In this scenario, instead of using one background images,you can use two different background images one for Portrait mode and one for Landscape mode.

Create two different folders of layout

1. /res/layout/
2. /res/layout-land/

Put you layout xml in both of these folders with different background images

For Example

```
1. /res/layout/
<RelativeLayout 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/background-port">
    <!-- layout code will go here -->
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Second layout will have different background image (created for landscape mode)

```
 2. /res/layout-land/
            <RelativeLayout 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@drawable/background-land">
            <!-- layout code will go here -->
            </RelativeLayout>
```

This is not direct answer of your question which is about using scaleType in RelativeLayout but the standard way by which your issue can be resolved

Also if your background image does not contain complex graphics or textures, think about using Nine-patch drawables for background. In this case you won't have to create different folders as mentioned above. Please check [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for more information